# CSS3 Transitions from 'left' property to 'right' property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a slider portfolio for my website.

The issue that I am having is that each section to be perfectly space out from each other. With jQuery, I then change the classes and let CSS handle the animations. Essentially, I am changed the left property with percentages. However, 10% from the left is not the equivalent to 90% from the left so I have to do 10% from the left and 10% from the right. However, when the CSS transitions do not take into account that I am switching from the left to right property.

Here is my website: http://devdesigned.com/intrinsecus

Note: At the moment, it only works for -webkit browsers because I have not gone in to add the other compatibility CSS.

Comment: you mean you want to get rid of that jump when u start rotating it to the left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your boxes have the same width. Use margin-left:-box_width/2; and now you'll only have to use percentage from left. 85% left will be the same as 15% right. Just do not forget to add some responsive design so the boxes won't be cut off.